# C# Parsing only Numbers from Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

Is there a simple way to parse only the number values from a combobox without having to create a ComboBox class?  My current combobox has 2 options: "0 (No)" and "1 (Yes)"

I was previously using

```
double comboValue = double.Parse(cmbValue.Text);
```

But am getting errors now because I added in the "Yes" and "No" to each option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you could simply use the SelectedIndex property of the combobox, rather than attempting to parse the text or convert the objects (which I guess are strings or some object with a ToString() implementation).

Note that I'm assuming you don't expect to have non-integer values (i.e. 0.5 "Maybe") at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SelectedValue` property instead of `.Text`

```
double comboValue = double.Parse(cmbValue.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

If you don't want to create class and if the combobox has only two values, then you can simply write an if condition.

```
double comboValue;
if(cmbValue.Text ==  "0 (No)") 
    comboValue = 0;
else
    comboValue = 1;
```

Comment: It depends on what the value is. If the combobox is populated by strings, then it won't make a difference. This is one where there should really be an object with a value and `ToString` implementation - although OP said he would rather not for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it in such a way:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items = new List<KeyValuePair<int,string>>();
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "NO"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "YES"));
comboBox1.DataSource = items;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "key";
```

Then, when you need to get selected value, just:

```
int selItem = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

It will return 0 if you have selected "NO", and 1 if you have selected "YES"

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use an Extension method on 'string' class as following:

```
public static class ExtensionTest
{
    public static int ToComboNumber(this string input)
    {
        if (input == "Yes")
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int number = comboBox1.Text.ToComboNumber();
        MessageBox.Show(number.ToString());
    }        
}
```

Extension methods are good to be used with enums and booleans too.
Note the 'static' keyword on both class and method.